# list alphanumerically but hidden first

Tags: shortcut-keys, find

Is there any Combination of OPTION possible with `ls`  which (in UBUNTU **14.04**)

For ease, I took below annotation to let you tell the situation

```
 H == Hidden directories (folder) and hidden files (name started with `.`)
```

1. lists all but sort *H* first and then non *H*, alphanumerically and sort folder before files.

   **`ls -A`**    is near to my solution . see [image: screenshot]

But `Desktop` breaks the chain

**PS**:  Kindly do not gives the other way hack,  like `ls (*)` or using `grep` . I am only looking for combination of OPTIONS . like `ls -ABC` or whatever.

### Update

Got answer of my second question . Thanks to [Edward](https://askubuntu.com/users/294611/edward-torvalds).

2. lists only *H* alphanumerically and sort folder before files.

   `ls -Ad .*` is best fit .

Comment: No there isn't any, but it's a good idea! You can always *try* to get an additional sort option defined by e-mailing the address at the end of `ls --help` You can even write the code yoursef and e-mail them the code! (that will get their attention more then just an email)

Comment: in second part of question do you mean hidden files as well as hidden directory ?

Comment: Yes Sir, hidden files and hidden directories sorted in alphanumerically manner.

Comment: I posted an answer

Answer (score 2):

**I am just answering 2nd part of your question, because 1st part is not possible using just `ls` command.**

**to list only hidden files and only hidden directories sorted in alphanumerically manner. folders will come in alphabetically order(along with files), not before files**

```
ls -a1d .*
```

- `-a` gives you all file/directory hidden or not
- `-1` gives you one result per row
- `-d` stops `ls` from listing subdirectories and files inside any folder it comes accross
- `.*` wild card allows to list only hidden file/directory

Comment: @fabby what you say ?

Comment: @diecho thik hai bhai ?

Comment: best hai bhai.ab pahle ka kuch mil jaye to baat ban jaye